# How to add variables to twig template from js object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

I want to add variables to twig file from js object. I get this object in request as `response.context`.  `isMakeLogoExists`, `baseUrl`, `logoImg` are in this object. Is this possible somehow to pass this object and use key/value as variables in twig file?

```js
(function () {
        var request = window.location.href.split("?")[1];

        $.get( baseUrl + '/offers_ajax?' + request, function( data ) {

            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.dir( response.context );
        });

    })();
```

```html
{% if isMakeLogoExists %}
    <div class="main-logo make-logo">
        <a href="{{ baseUrl }}">
            <img id="logo" src="{{baseUrl}}/images/{{ logoImg }}" alt="Logo" >
            <span class="logo-make-text">{{ year  }} {{ vehicle }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="main-logo">
        <a href="{{ baseUrl }}">
            <img id="logo" src="{{baseUrl}}/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" >
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: twig templates are parsed on server-side, javascript objects exists only on client-side. So this wont work. You have to manipulate the html with javascript on client-side.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions oh shit. Really. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's simply not possible.** The one is server-side and the other is client-side.

**EDIT:** It is possible with an ajax call - but in the most cases a no-go. There are better techniques and best-practices out there.

Comment: Yeah, now I got it. Thank you!

Comment: `Not possible` is quite extreme, OP can relay on `ajax` and modify his `HTML` on the output of the request

Comment: But Twig is not build for js, its server-side for php - not to be rude but in a big scaled project for example it would be a no-go to let js Influence your backend twig architecture.

Comment: So what then if you are using a type of `http caching` (generated by Twig or whatever) and you would need to display the amount of items in a shopping cart, show wether the shop is open at this very moment, ...

Comment: But that would not be a template value change? Such things would be realized with frontend js and send status updates to the backend? Template values are backend and stay backend - also for security reasons? I'll update my answer because you made a good point.